# Using Poisson distribution to calculate probabilites from 4 classes

Tags: probability, sampling, poisson-distribution

In a population of four classes of individuals, the proportion of individuals of Class $i$ is $p_i$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. Suppose you sample independently from this population, and suppose the sample size is a Poisson random variable with parameter $n$ for a fixed positive integer $n$.

This was a homework problem I had that dealt with plotting distributions. I've added two questions about calculations that I don't understand how to solve.

> 1) What is the probability that a randomly taken sample contains at least
>   one individual from each class?
>
> 2) What is the probability that in 50 trials you get at least two of each
>   kind of individual.

I am trying to manipulate the Poisson formula, but I cannot see how I should include all the variables. Something I am thinking is that for 1) a partition is necessary (to add 4 different poisson distributions) or probably it will look like ($1 -$ no individual from each class). How would I calculate both these problems?